# UIButton action handle inside table view cell

Tags: ios, dictionary, uitableview

[image: i have a table view like this]

I have a table view like this.

What i did was, I created a separate class for my cell, and i have IBAction in the .m file which i created for the cell.

In my TableViewController class i have got a dictionary which is retrieved by a web service.[im loading these details from that.] Now I want to send something back to my web service by clicking accept button.

Since my details dictionary is in TableViewController class and the IBAction is in separate class i have no idea how to do that. i know the logic how to do that. but i have no idea how do i get the certain information from my dictionary variable which is inside tableviewControler's cellForRowAtIndexPath method..

Can anyone give me some idea ? please...

Edit:

here my cellForRowAtIndexPath method

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {
  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
   TacleCell *cell = (TacleCell*)[tableView     dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

NSDictionary *tempDictionary= [self.googlePlaces objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSString* FirstName = [[tempDictionary valueForKey:@"PatientProfile"]valueForKey:@"FirstName"];
NSString* LastName = [[tempDictionary valueForKey:@"PatientProfile"]valueForKey:@"LastName"];
//NSString* FullName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",FirstName,LastName];

cell.Time.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@",[[[tempDictionary valueForKey:@"Appointment"]valueForKey:@"DayTimeSlot"]valueForKey:@"StartTime"], [[[tempDictionary valueForKey:@"Appointment"]valueForKey:@"DayTimeSlot"]valueForKey:@"EndTime"]];




cell.Name.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",FirstName,LastName];

cell.profileImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bookmark.png"];
// cell.textLabel.text = [[tempDictionary valueForKey:@"Appointment"]valueForKey:@"AgencyName"];

if([[tempDictionary valueForKey:@"Appointment"]valueForKey:@"AgencyId"] != NULL)
{
    cell.Date.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"AppoinmentID: %@",[[tempDictionary valueForKey:@"Appointment"]valueForKey:@"AgencyId"]];
}
else
{
    cell.Date.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Not Rated"];
}

return cell;
```

}

in tempDictionary i have something to use.and that value should pass to the service by pressing Accept button.. that is what i want to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The delegation pattern is just what you need for that. Here is a [good documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html).
You should make your `TableViewController` a `delegate` of `tableViewCell`.

MYCell.h:

```
@class MYCell;

@protocol MYCellDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)buttonTappedInCell:(MYCell *)cell;

@end

@interface MYCell : UITableViewCell

@property (weak, nonatomic) id<MYCellDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

MYCell.m:

```
...
- (IBAction)buttonCliked:(id)sender
{
    [self.delegate buttonTappedInCell:self];
}
```

MYTableViewController.m:

```
...
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath
{
    MYCell *cell = /// Create your cell
    cell.delegate = self;

    return cell;
}

- (void)buttonTappedInCell:(MYCell *)cell
{
   ///  Send something back to your web service 
}
```

Comment: actually i am new to IOS.. i don't have idea about delegates.. can you explain with a code or.. can you give me some tutorials about it..[regarding my question]

Comment: thank you .. i will search about it and try it out :)

Comment: sir i have a question... in MYTAbleviewControler.m class below the cellForIndexPath i have to implement my click event right ? so this method have my cell parameter too.. is IOS itself pass the cell to this method ??

Comment: Not sure I understood your question. Could you please post what you have in `cellForIndexPath` method? The idea was to just keep whatever you have there and add `cell.delegate = self;` line.

Comment: i have posted it sir... can you check it out ?

Answer (score 1):

in below UITABLEVIEWDATASOURCE method,

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)
{
// give buttons to your cell`s contentview.

then,
[Acceptbutton or CancelButton  addTarget:nil action:@selector(yourbtnselector:) forControlEvents:UIcontrolEventTouchUPInside];

}
```

then,
in Button selector,

```
-(voide)ButtonSelector: (id)sender
{

if(sender == accept Button)
{
// DO your Stuff.
}

if(sender == Cancel Button)
{
// DO your Stuff.
}


}
```

so, you dont need to implement Tableview didselectrow method for your case.

Comment: sir i can understand what you have proposed exept one thing...in cellforRowatIndexpath methode you have mentioned give buttons to your cells content view.. what is that? you mean instance for the buttons ? can you explain it further ?

Comment: you can alloc , init your button in cellforrow atindexpath, then set position of it according to your need in cell, then do [cell.contentview addsubview: your button];   Do it for implement CustomCell, programatically.

Comment: If answer help you then accept & giving up it, for refrence of other people

Answer (score 1):

Answer to your doubt after @dariaa's solution is when you click on the button that will call action method which is in MyCell class and there again delegete hand over's the control back through the method([self.delegate buttonTappedInCell:self]) along with parameter self(current class object) to the controller class from where button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

There 2 simple solutions for that:

- Using custom protocols. Here's [a link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html)! .
- Using Key-Value Observing. Here's [a link](http://nshipster.com/key-value-observing/)!

My suggest is using custom protocol.